# Changing the pressed image resource by code

Tags: android, android-layout

Is it possible to do some image affects on images to simulate pressed state? (to reduce the size of the APK)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_pressed="true"
           android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" /> <!-- pressed -->
     <item android:state_focused="true"
           android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" /> <!-- focused -->
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" /> <!-- default -->
 </selector>
```

and then each button can be defined in XML as well:

button_normal:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#DD63594A"
        android:endColor="#809C7D5A"
        android:angle="90"/>
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#FF524539" />
        <!-- android:dashWidth="2dp" android:dashGap="1dp" /> -->
    <padding android:left="4dp"
        android:top="4dp"
        android:right="4dp"
        android:bottom="4dp"/>
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
        android:topLeftRadius="7dp" android:topRightRadius="7dp"/>
</shape>
```

button_pressed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#80A57D08"
        android:endColor="#DDE75D31"
        android:angle="90"/>
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#FF524539" />
       <!-- android:dashWidth="2dp" android:dashGap="1dp" /> -->
    <padding android:left="4dp"
        android:top="4dp"
        android:right="4dp"
        android:bottom="4dp"/>
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
        android:topLeftRadius="7dp" android:topRightRadius="7dp"/> 
</shape>
```

button_focused:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#80E75D31"
        android:endColor="#DDE75D31"
        android:angle="90"/>
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#FF524539" />
        <!-- android:dashWidth="2dp" android:dashGap="1dp" /> --> 
    <padding android:left="4dp"
        android:top="4dp"
        android:right="4dp"
        android:bottom="4dp"/>
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
        android:topLeftRadius="7dp" android:topRightRadius="7dp"/> 
</shape>
```

As far as animation, it really depends on what you want to do and to what end:

You can make your own (frame-by-frame) for example: http://www.twintechs.com/2008/06/frame-by-frame-xml-animation-with-google-android/ & http://code.google.com/p/android-animation-example/

Or use AnimatedViews: http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2008/04/animated-views.html

Hope that helps. That will save space ;-)

FYI: If you are looking for compression look no further than http://trimage.org/